# JQuery Hover - Overlay appears. Instead, client wants overlay to be there and then disappear with hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress theme. It uses Jquery to have the following effect: when you hover over a thumbnail, an overlay appears. Instead, my client wants the overlay to be present, and then when you hover, it reveals the thumbnail underneath. Any suggestions on altering this code to have that effect?

Thanks

```
function gdl_portfolio_hover(selector){
    selector.each(function(){
        jQuery(this).hover(function(){
            var thumbnail_hover = jQuery(this).find('a.hover-wrapper');
            var thumbnail_overlay_hover = thumbnail_hover.children();

            thumbnail_overlay_hover.fadeIn(200);
        }, function(){
            var thumbnail_hover = jQuery(this).find('a.hover-wrapper');
            var thumbnail_overlay_hover = thumbnail_hover.children();

            thumbnail_overlay_hover.fadeOut(200);
        });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts? if so, what did you observe? did you try to recreate the functionality stand-alone to simplify it using something like [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net). If so, can we have the link to it so we can fiddle, too?

Comment: I barely know any javascript. I messed around with a little (see comment to SomeBigF**Idiot's answer

Comment: I'll try jsfiddle and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

This may be stupid, but have you tried switching the meat of the two functions?

Comment: Worth a try.. Orginially you see a thumbnail. if you hover over the thumbnail, a overlay appears (fadeIn) and when you move the cursor away the overlay disappears (fadeOut). I switched fadeIn and fadeOut.  Still it's just the thumbnail, but now if you hover over nothing happens, but when you move away the overlay appears.  I would like the overlay to be there from the start though...